# How to perform user login after smartcard authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, smartcard

We are implementing smart card access to a 3rd party IIS asp (classic and .net) application hosted internally on our site. We are having a problem logging the user into the app after they have been card authenticated. Due to upgrades, patches, licensing, etc to the 3rd party app, we don't want to touch their code.

Is it possible to create a new page that calls the original login page, passes in the username and password, then after successfully logging in, releases control to the user?

We have tried HttpWebRequest which gets only so far through the login processing but redirects to an error page due to session information getting lost when a classic page gets called from the .net side. We think this may be due to cookies not being synced or something missing in the request that would allow everything to be picked up and carried along.

Is HttpWebRequest the proper object to be using for this?

```
<%@ Import namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" theme="Default" culture="auto" uiculture="auto" EnableViewState="false" %>
<%
  CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 
  ArrayList theQueryData = new ArrayList(); 

  HttpWebRequest theRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servernm/Login.aspx"); 
  theRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
  theRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
  theRequest.Method = "POST"; 

  theQueryData.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "UserName", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("joe"))); 
  theQueryData.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "Password", HttpUtil  ity.UrlEncode("joep"))); 
  theQueryData.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "__EVENTTARGET", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("SignIn"))); 
  theQueryData.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "__EVENTARGUMENT", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("")));     
  string Parameters = String.Join("&", (String[])theQueryData.ToArray(typeof(string))); 
  theRequest.ContentLength = Parameters.Length; 

  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(theRequest.GetRequestStream()); 
  sw.Write(Parameters); 
  sw.Close(); 

  HttpWebResponse theResponse = (HttpWebResponse)theRequest.GetResponse(); 

  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theResponse.GetResponseStream()); 
  HttpStatusCode code = theResponse.StatusCode; 
  //return sr.ReadToEnd(); 
  Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
%>
```

Thanks